# How to specify default user in mac OS when running the mysql command in terminal?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-cli

I'm on mac OS Catalina 10.15.2 with a fresh install of mysql. I'm getting the following output when running the commands `mysql` or `mysql -v`:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'timothyfisher'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This is because the user isn't set to `root` in my case. MySQL works just fine as I can enter with `mysql -u root`, so this isn't really causing any problems but it gets kind of annoying.

How can I set the mysql command to use the root user instead of my computer user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file ~/.my.cnf and add following lines.

```
[client]
user=<your_user>
password=<your_password>
```

> More info can see https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/mycnf-preference/.

Comment: Doing this logs me straight into mysql without showing the output of the command though. Normally if you run `mysql -v` it shows just the version, or if you run `mysql` alone it will show a list of commands. With this if I type in either of those it just throws me directly into mysql to start running queries.

Comment: `mysql -v` is verbose mode. you want to say is `mysql -V` ?